# if else block is not printing out statement for rock paper scissors game

Tags: java

hey all I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I have been making a rock paper scissors game in java through netbeans IDE. I know Ive seen alot of questions regarding this but in my if else statements I am trying to get it to print out some statements if a condition is met. It does it if player 1 throws rock and player two throws anything, including a tie, but anything else than that is not printing out the statement when ran. my code is below, know you guys like specific question and smaller sections of code but i feel the need to post the full code to see where I went wrong. if that makes sense! thanks for any help.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String personPlay; //Player A -- "R", "P", or "S"
    String secondUser; //Player B
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
    System.out.println("Player 1Please enter your name");
    String name1;
    name1 = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Hello " + name1);
    System.out.println("Hello Player 2");
    System.out.println("Player 2 Please enter your name");
    String name2;
    name2 = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Hello "+name2);
    System.out.println(name1 + "  enter r for Rock, p for Paper, s for Scissors: ");   //Get player's play -- note that this is stored as a string
    personPlay = scan.next();
    personPlay = personPlay.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(name2 + " enter r for Rock, p for Paper, and s for Scissors");
    secondUser = scan.next();
    secondUser = secondUser.toLowerCase();


    if (personPlay.equals(secondUser)) {
       System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    } else if (personPlay.equals("r")) {
       if (secondUser.equals("s")) {
          System.out.println("Rock beats scissors! Victory to "+name1);
       } else if (secondUser.equals("p")) {
          System.out.println("Paper beats Rock! Victory to "+name2);
       } if (personPlay.equals("p")) {
          if (secondUser.equals("s")) {
              System.out.println("Scissors cut Paper! Victory to "+name2);
          } else if (secondUser.equals("r")) {
              System.out.println("Paper covers rock! Victory to "+name1);
          } if (personPlay.equals("s")) {
              if (secondUser.equals("p")) {
                  System.out.println("Scissors beat paper! Victory to "+name1);
              }
          } else if (secondUser.equals("r")) {
              System.out.println("Rock beats Scissors! Victory to "+name2);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should break this up into methods and you can combine conditionals in `if` statements to increase readability.

Comment: Let your IDE reformat your code. Perhaps with correct indentation it will become clear to you where the logic is going wrong.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. Step through each line and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: it's not a problem with using debugger i think. I know I'm close to a successful program. I figured it has to be some sort of bracket error.

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions that check if the person threw paper (`"p"`) or scissors (`"s"`) or nested inside the condition that the person threw rock (`"r"`) and thus will never be true.

You need to check if the person threw paper or scissor in separate `else if` cases after you've checked for rock.

```
} else if (personPlay.equals("r")) {
    if (secondUser.equals("s")) {
        System.out.println("Rock beats scissors! Victory to "+name1);
    } else if (secondUser.equals("p")) {
      System.out.println("Paper beats Rock! Victory to "+name2);
    }
} else if (personPlay.equals("p")) {
    // Test second user is rock and scissors here
} else if (personPlay.equals("s")) {
    // Test second user is paper and rock here
}
```

You should also add some validation checks so that the entries made by both players are limited to the 3 legal choices.

Comment: Takes some courage to go through the code posted by the OP. +1

Comment: So I checked my code to see what you were talking about, again fairly new to this, I tried redoing to the brackets to make sure it wasn't nested, and put else if statements in accordingly, didn't work sadly, i probablly screwed it up. I tried rewriting the code with only if statements. that did it. seems more crude but i got it running. thanks for the help, just trying to understand how to get better and after reading the comments format my code better. cheers.